# How to achive proper typing when merging array of objects into object of array

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, which is doing exactly what I want to, however I get a type error from the compiler

```js
type A = {
    foo: number,
    bar: string
}

type B = {
    [key in keyof A]: Array<A[key]>
}

const a: A[] = [
    {
        bar: '42',
        foo: 42
    },
    {
        bar: '1337',
        foo: 1337
    }
]

const b: B = a.reduce((prev, current) => {
    (Object.keys(current) as (keyof A)[])
        // going with ts-ignore here results in running code with the behaviour I want
        .forEach(key => prev[key].push(current[key])); // type error here: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
    return prev;
}, {
    foo: [],
    bar: []
} as B)
```

I understand that the problem is that the intersection type of the keys `string & number === never` is the problem here, but I do not quite understand how to fix this.
Also I am looking for a solution which allows me to iterate over all the keys, the type I am working with has a lot more properties.

So far I tried different ways of iterating over keys and explicit type checking of the keys, but without success.

Comment: :/ I would just cast to never to avoid headaches (with a comment explaining why, maybe).

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectKeys<O extends {}>(o: O): (keyof O)[] {
    return Object.keys(o) as any;
}

let b2 = Object.fromEntries(
    objectKeys(a[0])
        .map(k => [k, a.map(e => e[k])])
) as B
```

Object.fromEntries has pretty weak typing so it's easily casted by `as`